# Converting this logic condition possible without programming?

Tags: logic-gates

I've been busy trying to make a relay print which has 8 inputs of around 6V-24V that powers the relay. However, I want to add a dipswitch which is able reverse the input-relay relation behavior. Meaning;

(DIPSWITCH = TRUE) **The relay gets powered by default and by adding an input of 6-24V disables it.**

(DIPSWITCH = FALSE) **The relay is off by default and by adding an input of 6-24V enables it.**

I want to make this without **programming** for learning purposes since I wanted to see if this is even possible without a microprocessor and programmable logic arrays.

This is the FBD with my intended function.

[image]
Which translates to:

```
If (signal_6V == HIGH && dipswitch == LOW){
  relay = HIGH;
}

If (signal_6V == LOW && dipswitch == LOW){
  relay = LOW;
}

If (signal_6V == HIGH && dipswitch == HIGH){ //Inverted because of the dipswitch
  relay = LOW;
}

If (signal_6V == LOW && dipswitch == HIGH){ //Inverted because of the dipswitch
  relay = HIGH;
}
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAi2d6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is what I have now and it does now the following:

```
If (signal_6V == HIGH && dipswitch == HIGH){ //Inverted because of the dipswitch
  relay = LOW;
}

If (signal_6V == LOW && dipswitch == HIGH){ //Inverted because of the dipswitch
  relay = HIGH;
}
```

However, this does only 2 of the 4 conditions and violates the other conditions. I've been thinking for so long and I can't seem to figure it out to make it work without a microprocessor. My questions is if this is possible and what do I minimally need for it? For those who wants to help me out fully, you can always add a schematic, thank you in advance!

Comment: Arrggh!  Could you fix the formatting on the (pseudo) code sections?

Comment: Use the `{}` code button or 4 x space to format your code.

Comment: So you need an ex-or gate?

Comment: useful and widely adopted coding standard for C to be aware of: [Barr Group embedded C coding standard](https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/Books/Embedded-C-Coding-Standard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic can be rewritten much more simply as a table.

```
Signal DIP | Relay
-----------+-------
  0     0  |   off
  0     1  |   on
  1     0  |   on
  1     1  |   off
```

It now becomes clear that this is an XOR, exclusive OR, function.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSf2tW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The XOR logic effectively acts as a buffer or inverter depending on the position of SW1.*

XOR chips are available in all logic families. If you choose an XNOR (inverting) instead then tie R1 to V+ rather than ground.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the switch and a "signal source"?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLhg4E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or you can build the circuit using only relays.